# How to refresh file when changes are detected in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

My colleague and I are working on the same project in PhpStorm shared in network, and it happens that we are editing the same Javascript file, however when I change the file, there is a delay for the update file on his computer and it's the same with me. Is there a way to make the PhpStorm update the file when it detects a change? Without this delay?

Comment: @markcial You mean's GIT right? We are avoiding it...

Comment: Git, SVN, mercurial and more. Why try to avoid it?

Comment: @Blaatpraat The project just don't need it, it's not very complex. I just wanna know if exist anything in IDE that allow edit the same file shared in network at the same time...

Comment: i am unable to see a reason to avoid a version control system, i mean that the advantages are way more than the disadvantages. Even simple projects are a perfect fit for a versioning system.

Comment: `File | Synchronize` to re-read project files. This will work IF project files are located on network share and you accessing them directly .. although it may work weird (random delay/freezes for no reason) -- depends on your network and other aspects as it works OK for some and works very bad for others, that's why it's not recommended to work this way. Better have own local copy and deploy to remote when needed (automatically). too bad that such auto-deployment works one way only -- local to remote.

Comment: Got it... There should be some plugin that works with several changes in real time and enables programmers saw the changes from one another such as Cloud9...

Comment: Use a VCS. Now! Before you lose code. There is no project too small to not benefit from using a VCS. Any VCS. I have repositories that contain only 1 or 2 files and I am the only one that works on them.

Comment: @axiac we will work on it...

Comment: PhpStorm is not a tool for collaborative editing. It can check if the file was modified by another process and reload it but when this happens and you also have unsaved changes then you have a conflict. You have to solve it before being able to save your changes and I don't know how PhpStorm handles this. Does it open the two versions side by side for comparison? Or it asks you to choose one and discard the other? Sure, conflicts also happen when using a VCS but that's a different situation. In a VCS you have the files on disk, they can be accessed and compared easily and there is no rush.

Comment: @axiac It can do all 3: discard local, overwrite with external or manual merge (via diff viewer).

Comment: In this case it seems it can be used for collaborative editing, with attention.

Answer (score 3):

Go to File>Synchronize to refresh the files in the project or Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> in windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> in Mac.
 
[image]

Comment: I had seen this command, but I would not want to stay all time doing this command, is there not a way to automate this every time the PhpStorm recognize a change in the file update it?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki, hmm, then you must be needing a version control system ( as already people have mentioned in the comments in your question ) as it might happen that your code gets deleted when your colleague saves his code. That is too risky.

Comment: @CaioKawasaki It already does: when you switching between apps. Problem is: it's not that reliable when working over network directly. Better use VCS.

Answer (score 3):

You could manually reload file changes by clicking `File > Synchronize`, if it's not reloading automatically.

And for automatic reload go to `File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings` and under `Synchronization` section check **Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation** and save this settings by pressing `OK`. That's it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Responsible for the delay you encounter is not PhpStorm but the network. Even on local networks, it takes some time (seconds) for changes to propagate to other computers. The reason in not in hardware but in the way the network sharing is implemented in software.

The programs can subscribe to get notified by the OS about events on a specified file or directory. When an event happens, the programs on the local computer that subscribed are notified almost instantly. This is not possible when the files are on another computer; the changes on the remote drive are visible to local programs when the network sharing software on the two computers exchange information about what happened sync their last communication.

Because network communication takes time and resources, the sharing programs usually publish their information in batches. If a file changes it waits some time (let's say half of second), maybe some other change happens and it can publish both in a single batch. If nothing happens then it decides it's the time to inform the other computers in the network about the changes.

It's also possible that PhpStorm queries the file status from time to time. Again, because of network overload it cannot do it continuously; it would be a waste of processing time and resources.

I think using your current setup this is the best you can get.